# Passagem de uma struct como parâmetro

Tags: c, struct

Boa tarde! Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou com duvida nesse exercício... não estou conseguindo passar por parâmetro a *struct* para outra função.
OBS: estou começando agora... é aconselhável manter as *structs* na *main* ou em escopo global?

```
void menorIdade(aluno){ //????
    
    int compIdade;
    printf("\nDigite uma idade: ");
    scanf("%d", &compIdade);
    
    printf("\nALUNOS COM IDADE MENOR QUE %d", compIdade);
    for(int i=0; i<qtdAlunos; i++){
        if(aluno[i].idade<compIdade){
            printf("\n%s - %d", aluno[i].nome,aluno[i].idade);
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    struct turma {
        char nome[50];
        int idade;
        int numeroReg;
    } aluno[qtdAlunos];

    
    for(int i=0; i<qtdAlunos; i++){
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        
        printf("\nALUNO %d", i+1);
        printf("\nNome: ");
        fgets(aluno[i].nome, 50, stdin);
        
        
        printf("Idade: ");
        scanf("%d", &aluno[i].idade );
        
        printf("Numero de registro: ");
        scanf("%d", &aluno[i].numeroReg );

    }
    menorIdade(struct turma aluno); //???
}
```

Comment: A sua `struct turma` precisa ser conhecida em sua função `menorIdade`, além disso `aluno` é um array de structs e não uma única struct. Declare-a em escopo global para que seja conhecida tanto na main quanto na função menorIdade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> é aconselhável manter as structs na main ou em escopo global?

Sim, é aconselhável e muitas vezes essencial já que todo o projeto vai trabalhar com elas. A regra geral é usar sempre o mínimo escopo possível, e não alocar nada no espaço global

> não estou conseguindo passar por parâmetro a struct para outra função

Vou te mostrar um exemplo, digitado em cima de seu programa. E escrevendo a partir dos dados

#### Sobre seu programa

Antes vou escrever sobre seu programa...

```
struct turma {
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    int numeroReg;
} aluno[qtdAlunos];
```

Essa construção é um tanto folclórica. Então `aluno` é um vetor de `turma`? Não te parece estranho? `aluno` é `turma[]`, quando a realidade é o contrário: a `turma` é uma coleção de `aluno`

**Escreva seu programa em torno dos dados**. Sempre. E não escreva uma única linha sem razão. E não fique lendo dados em um programa que está testando. Vai levar a vida toda à toa. Use constantes ou funções geradoras de dados. NUNCA leia. Quando estiver segura do programa você coloca a leitura. Vai ver isso no exemplo.

**E como começar esse lance de escrever em torno dos dados?**

É claro que vamos ler uma turma para poder listar os caras com idade menor que um valor. Então a primeira coisa que precisa é de um objetivo. Então no próprio IDE usa algo assim

```
Seq        Mat                 Nome   Id
001..12345678..01234567890123456789..100
001  12345678  01234567890123456789  100
001..12345678..01234567890123456789..100
001  12345678  01234567890123456789  100

        XXX alunos
```

É muito mais fácil quando tem um objetivo ANTES.

É claro que pra testar a função precisa poder listar a turma toda ou não vai saber ou poder provar que está tudo certo. Então vai precisa de uma função para mostrar os caras todos. Sempre que criar uma estrutura crie uma função assim porque mesmo que o enunciado não peça você vai querer listar. Como vai testar isso direito sem ela? Então pode ser

```
    int         mostra_turma( Turma* T );
```

Sem pensar: a função recebe o endereço de uma struct `Turma`. E lista os caras. Claro.

Mas claro que mostrar todo mundo é a mesma coisa que mostrar os caras abaixo de uma certa idade, então a outra função

```
int         menorIdade( Turma* T, Num idade );
```

deve ser a mesma, certo? `Num` é um número, como um `int`. Não faz diferença agora.

#### e a Turma

Em C existe essa prática comum de nomear as struct com a primeira Letra em maiúscula, e só ela. E nomear constantes com TODAS as letras em maiúsculas. Se seguir isso vai ajudar você a entender os programas dos outros e vice-versa.

Uma `Turma` é uma coleção de alunos. Eis uma possibilidade

```
typedef struct
{
    Num     id;

    Aluno   aluno[MAX_ALUNOS_];
    Num     qtdAlunos;
    char    nome[50];

}   Turma;
```

Veja a diferença aqui: a `Turma` tem um nome, um `id` porque é legal ter um campo numérico para poder comparar, uma quantidade de `Aluno` e um vetor de `Aluno` com um tamanho fixo alocado, afinal estamos começando em C e não vai querer alocar memória e tal. E é bem melhor ter informações sobre a Turma DENTRO do registro. Compare com o seu caso em que precisa controlar um único vetor de struct com um certo número de ocorrências e entenda que vai ter que manter um contador só para isso. E se tivesse mais de uma `Turma` estaria bem encrencada...

Note que ao usar a convenção de que falei já fica claro que `Turma`, `Aluno` e `Num` são tipos definidos em seu programa, e `MAX_ALUNOS_` é uma constante. Uma convenção, mas ajuda demais.

#### e Aluno?

O que tinha no programa original

```
typedef struct
{
    Num     id; // para escrever menos :) 

    Num     idade;
    char    nome[50];
    
}   Aluno;
```

O simples. o `id` pode não ser a matrícula, mas vamos usar como tal. A vantagem é que sabe que `Turma` tem `Aluno` e pode mudar uma struct sem mexer na outra

#### os dados então:

Se está mesmo lendo isso notou que não temos programa mas temos o modelo e duas funções, e um gabarito para o relatório. ANTES de escrever o programa, porque começamos com os dados.

Eis os dados até aqui:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ALUNOS_ 10

typedef     unsigned int Num; // para escrever menos

typedef struct
{
    Num     id; // para escrever menos :) 

    Num     idade;
    char    nome[50];
    
}   Aluno;


typedef struct
{
    Num     id;

    Aluno   aluno[MAX_ALUNOS_];
    Num     qtdAlunos;
    char    nome[50];

}   Turma;

// aqui vao as funcoes
int         menorIdade( Turma*, Num );
int         mostra_turma( Turma* );

// fim de turma.h
```

Como sugere a última linha isso estará gravado no arquivo *"header.h"* do EXEMPLO que estou te mostrando e será incluído no programa. o tal

```
#include
```

- Não aloca nada
- define `Num`, `Aluno` e `Turma` de um jeito que deve servir
- `Num` é um `int` sem sinal porque faz sentido.
- `MAX_ALUNOS_` vale 10. Está bom. Não faz diferença

#### E as funções?

São duas, na verdade uma. e já dá pra escrever porque tem o gabarito lá em cima. Foi a primeira coisa que escrevemos. Elas vão estar no arquivo turma.c, o mesmo nome do header. Outra convenção. Importante.

```
int         mostra_turma( Turma* T)
{
    // claro que a listagem e a mesma que acima, so que vai listar todos
    return menorIdade( T, INT_MAX );
};
```

Essa foi fácil hein? Porque `INT_MAX` é um valor grande, o maior possível para um número, e então claro que vai listar todo mundo, e assim não precisa usar duas funções para fazer algo tão parecido. Claro podia ter usado 200 para listar os caras com menos de 200 anos. Ou ter escrito as duas como todo mundo. Uma para testar e outra para o enunciado, mas aí teria que se preocupar com o risco de mudar uma sem mudar a outra...

O valor de retorno de `mostra_turma()` podia ser o total de caras ou um valor negativo em caso de erro. Como ela recebe algo do tipo Turma*, um ponteiro para Turma, esse ponteiro pode ser nulo por exemplo e aí poderia retornar um código de erro, certo?

O exemplo retorna zero porque é um exemplo.

#### menor_idade() afinal

Esse é o programa afinal. Vou mostrar o exemplo e depois uns detalhes. É muito simples, claro, porque é só mostrar o que está no gabarito que foi a primeira coisa que a gente escreveu.

```
int         menorIdade( Turma* T, Num idade )
{
    const char* cab = "Seq       Mat                  Nome   Id\n";
    int t = 0; // conta os alunos
    if ( idade == INT_MAX )
        printf("Turma: '%s' [%d alunos]\n\n%s\n",
            T->nome,
            T->qtdAlunos,
            cab // o cabecalho comum
        );
    else
        printf("Turma: '%s' [%d alunos]. Limite: %d anos (inclusive)\n\n%s",
            T->nome,
            T->qtdAlunos,
            idade,
            cab
        );
    // agora lista um por um 
    for( int n = 0; n<T->qtdAlunos; n++)
    {
        if( T->aluno[n].idade <= idade )
        {
            printf("%3d  %8d  %20s  %3d\n",
            1+n, T->aluno[n].id, T->aluno[n].nome, T->aluno[n].idade 
            );
            t = t + 1;
        }
    };  // for()
    printf("\n\t%3d alunos\n\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

**Veja essa linha por exemplo:**

```
        const char* cab = "Seq       Mat                  Nome   Id\n";
```

O cabeçalho da listagem, copiado do próprio gabarito com recortar e colar. E os campos tem o tamanho em colunas numerado então não há como não ficar alinhadinho... A gene não quer ficar testando. Veja a linha que imprime o cabeçalho:

```
        printf("Turma: '%s' [%d alunos]\n\n%s\n",
            T->nome,
            T->qtdAlunos,
            cab // o cabecalho comum
        );
```

Se mudar de idéia sobre o cabeçalho não precisa procurar isso no meio do printf()...

**E a linha do aluno?**

```
            printf("%3d  %8d  %20s  %3d\n",
            1+n, T->aluno[n].id, T->aluno[n].nome, T->aluno[n].idade 
            );
```

Note o tamanho dos campos depois do %. assim garante que vai alinhar, antes de testar o programa. Afinal é pra ficar assim, como est;a lá em cima...

```
001  12345678  01234567890123456789  100
```

3, depois 8, depois 20 depois 3.

O `if` lá no começo é porque quando for listar por idade a gente precisa do valor na tela e quando for listar todo mundo nao...

O código vai te mostrar como acessar cada campo dentro das estruturas. Leia com cuidado.

#### montando turma.c

Então esse novo arquivo tem as funções que estão declaradas do header turma.h e o que for preciso para fazer com que elas rodem. Aqui não precisa de mais nada.

```
#include    "turma.h"

int         menorIdade( Turma* T, Num idade )
{
    const char* cab = "Seq       Mat                  Nome   Id\n";
    int t = 0; // conta os alunos
    if ( idade == INT_MAX )
        printf("Turma: '%s' [%d alunos]\n\n%s\n",
            T->nome,
            T->qtdAlunos,
            cab // o cabecalho comum
        );
    else
        printf("Turma: '%s' [%d alunos]. Limite: %d anos (inclusive)\n\n%s",
            T->nome,
            T->qtdAlunos,
            idade,
            cab
        );
    // agora lista um por um 
    for( int n = 0; n<T->qtdAlunos; n++)
    {
        if( T->aluno[n].idade <= idade )
        {
            printf("%3d  %8d  %20s  %3d\n",
            1+n, T->aluno[n].id, T->aluno[n].nome, T->aluno[n].idade 
            );
            t = t + 1;
        }
    };  // for()
    printf("\n\t%3d alunos\n\n", t);
    return 0;
}


int         mostra_turma( Turma* T)
{
    // claro que a listagem e a mesma que acima, so que vai listar todos
    return menorIdade( T, INT_MAX );
};

// fim de turma.c
```

Claro que a partir do `#include` todas as `struct` são conhecidas e pode chamar as funções aí dentro

#### porque não tem main()?

Deixando isso separado você pode escrever programas que usam essas funções pela vida toda, sem ter sequer que abrir esses arquivos de novo. E pode testar suas funções com vários possíveis `main()`. Ou pode vender suas funções para alguém que vai usar só o header e o código compilado, como você faz com `stdio.h` e `printf()` por exemplo...

#### Como criar uma Turma de teste

Como eu disse, é o diabo ficar lendo do usuário a cada vez que for testar o programa. Simplesmente não faz sentido.

**Veja isso:**

```
    Turma teste = 
    {   // uma turma de teste basta
        .id = 42,
        .qtdAlunos = 3,
        .nome = "Fisica II",
        .aluno[0] = { 42, 22, "Jhonny Cash" },
        .aluno[1] = { 45, 25, "Willie Nelson" },
        .aluno[2] = { 52, 30, "Kris Kristofferson" }
    };

    Turma*  p = &teste; // inutil: e so um exemplo
```

Aí está uma turma de teste, arrumadinha com 3 alunos já. Basta isso para nosso programa, que nunca rodou. Preste atenção para a notação: não é complicado.
Você precede o nome dos campos da struct por ponto. Usa chaves quando tiver uma struct dentro da outra, usa colchetes para índices do vetor. Nem é preciso inicializar todos os campos.

Note o exemplo de como declarar p como um ponteiro para Turma.

**E o teste em si?**

```
    mostra_turma( p );

    menorIdade( &teste, 12 ); // sem usar o ponteiro
    menorIdade( p, 25 ); // dois alunos
    menorIdade( p, 55 ); // todos
```

Isso já basta: mostra_turma(0 vai listar todos. O primeiro filtro por idade não vai achar ninguém, o segundo vai achar 2, um no limite de idade. O terceiro vai incluir todo mundo.

Eis **tmain.c**, esse programa de teste

```
#include "turma.h"

int main(void)
{
    Turma teste = 
    {   // uma turma de teste basta
        .id = 42,
        .qtdAlunos = 3,
        .nome = "Fisica II",
        .aluno[0] = { 42, 22, "Jhonny Cash" },
        .aluno[1] = { 45, 25, "Willie Nelson" },
        .aluno[2] = { 52, 30, "Kris Kristofferson" }
    };

    Turma*  p = &teste; // inutil: e so um exemplo

    mostra_turma( p );

    menorIdade( &teste, 12 ); // sem usar o ponteiro
    menorIdade( p, 25 ); // dois alunos
    menorIdade( p, 55 ); // todos
    
    return 0;
}

// fim de tmain.c
```

**Como compilar isso?**

```
gcc -o t -Wall -std=c17 tmain.c turma.c
```

Esse comando vai gerar o executável t, a partir dos fontes tmain.c e turma.c
Ou use seu IDE.

Os 3 arquivos estão separados aqui e basta copiar. O programa imprimiu certo da primeira vez. ;) a mesnos que se ache um erro a seguir. E não demorou nada para escrever. Muito menos para testar.

O que demora é explicar e escrever aqui :) mas eu queria mostrar um possível mecanismo a partir do zero, exceto pelo seu programa claro.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!!

Comment: É aconselhável manter as funções antes ou depois da main?

Comment: Em C não importa a ordem, mas é importante que esteja perto de onde elas são chamadas. Em Python por exemplo as funções obrigatoriamente devem ser declaradas antes de serem chamadas, mas em C não faz diferença.

Comment: A diferença não é para o compilador: E pra quem vai ler o código, inclusive o autor semanas depois. main() deve estar só em um arquivo separado porque é a realidade: produção e teste. Toda a razão de ter um arquivo com funções é poder usar em outros lugares. Se main() estiver junto não há como. Alguma ordem importa na hora de localizar o código mas os IDE modernos mantem uma lista em ordem alfabética então isso ficou menos importante. Só que nem todo mundo usa um IDE. @NatanFernandes grato pelas sugestões. Incorporei algumas

Comment: Entendi... obrigada novamente!